# Google's Barcode reader doesn't read code_39 barcode correctly in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services, barcode

I've implemented the google service barcode detector in my android app,some time ago.
(part of the Mobile vision API).
Untill now everything worked well.
All of my customers are using a code_39 barcode type, and all of them have only numbers in their barcode values.

Recently, a new customer of mine started using the app - the problem is that he has also letters in his barcode stickers.
For example:

> m-108

For some reason, the barcodeDetector detects it as

> +M-108

even when I tried defining the barcode type specifically (instead of Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)

```
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.CODE_39)
                .build();
```

It still doesn't recognize the barcode correctly (adding the plus sign, and reading lowercased m as uppercased m)

I tried to search this issue forever now, but couldn't find any clue.

I know that there are two types of code_39 - one of the is full ascii (which apreantly is my customer's using), but I can't find a way to define the barcodeDetector to treat it as full-ascii.

Comment: Couldn't you just decode the string yourself? E.g. based on [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_39#Full_ASCII_Code_39).

Comment: Very interesting idea. But how would I get the raw data? And then decode it? Thank you.

Comment: `getRawValue` or `getRawBytes` on the `Barcode` instance?

Comment: how can I decode `getRawBytes`? `getRawValue` returns the same value as `getDisplayValue`

Comment: @Michael your idea has eventually helped out solving this issue. I took the string that I got, and according to the table you refrenced, I used regex to replace all +Capital letters with the corresponding lower cased letters. Thank you very much for your help!